# Web3js Error: transaction type not supported - How to know supported transaction type?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, ethereumjs-tx

I'm trying to send a test transaction but am getting a "transaction type not supported" error, and I tried every transaction type supported in the [@ethereumjs/tx docs](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/tx).

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const Tx = require('@ethereumjs/tx');
const Common = require('@ethereumjs/common') 

const common = new Common.default({ chain: 'ropsten' })

const w3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<apikey>')

 const key = '3c9...'
 const address = '0x3c6E2d83dFAd3858B55C978576b0Ba697C50a43c'

var privateKey = Buffer.from(key, 'hex')

const rawTx = {
    nonce: w3.utils.toHex(0),
    from: address,
    to: '0xe381c25de995d62b453af8b931aac84fccaa7a62',
    gas: w3.utils.toHex(21000),
    value: w3.utils.toHex(0),
    chainId: w3.utils.toHex(3),
};

let tx = Tx.Transaction.fromTxData(rawTx, {common})
tx.sign(privateKey);

let tx_hash = w3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(w3.utils.toHex(tx))
  .on('receipt', console.log)
     .catch(e => console.log('e: ', e));
```

Additionally, is there an online resource to determine what transaction types are supported for each chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error comes from a bad formatting of your transaction.
In fact, it must be encoded in rlp format (`serialize()` function) before being sent to the node. In addition, you should change  `gas` to `gasLimit` and add a `gasPrice` property in the `rawTx` object.

Here is a working piece of code, taking these changes into account :

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const Tx = require('@ethereumjs/tx');
const Common = require('@ethereumjs/common') 

const common = new Common.default({ chain: 'ropsten' })

const w3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<apikey>')

 const key = '3c9...'
 const address = '0x3c6E2d83dFAd3858B55C978576b0Ba697C50a43c'

var privateKey = Buffer.from(key, 'hex')

const rawTx = {
    nonce: w3.utils.toHex(0), //to be incremented for each new transaction with this account
    from: address,
    to: '0xe381c25de995d62b453af8b931aac84fccaa7a62',
    gasLimit: w3.utils.toHex(21000),
    gasPrice: w3.utils.toHex(10e9), //10 Gwei
    value: w3.utils.toHex(0),
    //chainId: w3.utils.toHex(3), optional parameter
};

let tx = Tx.Transaction.fromTxData(rawTx, {common})
const signedTx = tx.sign(privateKey);
//encode the transaction in rlp format
const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize()

let tx_hash = w3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(w3.utils.toHex(serializedTx))
  .on('receipt', console.log)
     .catch(e => console.log('e: ', e));
```

Comment: `sendSignedTransaction` method is alias of `sendRawTransaction`: https://github.com/web3/web3.js/blob/3b22adf4ff4fec56ac6d9218d4c746b44ed40198/packages/web3-eth/src/index.js#L521